# Knockout JS prevent click event triggering on a specific child

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, event-handling

I've seen similar questions asked but I couldn't make it work for me with Knockout 'data-bind'

I have a parent div with some multiple divs inside. On the parent div I have a click event, that I do not want to fire on a specific child div that has some other event handling.

I have something like this:

```
<div class='parent' dataBind='click: parentClicked'>
  <div class='child' dataBind='click: childClicked'></div>
  ....some other stuff...
</div>
```

In my view model I tried:

```
function parentClicked() {
  alert('parent clicked');
}
function childClicked(event) {
  alert('child clicked');
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

I get that 'event.stopPropagation()' is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `clickBubble: false`. For reference: [Preventing the event from bubbling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

```
<div class='parent' dataBind='click: parentClicked'>
  <div class='child' dataBind='click: childClicked, clickBubble: false'></div>
  ....some other stuff...
</div>
```

Comment: not working if child is a checkbox